# how to execute a specific conditional query

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have two queries, and want to combine them. I want the first query to be executed only if a specific condition is met, and the second one executed based on another condition so only one of them should execute each time. Originally this was a SP, but I changed it to a query in order to be able to modify and deal with errors easily. 
Here are the queries, I combined them using join.

I can't separate them because I'll ll use them on a single report (crystal report with parameters)

---

1st query
Here i need to put an if statement that contain a parameter which will be declared as an int, if the parameter value is equal to  a certain value then this query will be executed and the second query will be ignored. If it doesn't t match here, then the value should be passed to the 2nd if statement in the second query.

```
SELECT     odrf.DocEntry, odrf.CntctCode,drf1.SubCatNum, odrf.Address2, drf1.LineNum, odrf.DocType, odrf.CANCELED, odrf.Handwrtten, odrf.DocStatus, odrf.Transfered, odrf.DocDate, odrf.DocDueDate,
                          odrf.CardCode, odrf.Printed, odrf.CardName, odrf.Address, odrf.NumAtCard, odrf.VatPercent, odrf.VatSum, odrf.VatSumFC, odrf.DiscPrcnt, odrf.DiscSumFC,
                          odrf.DiscSum, odrf.PaidToDate, odrf.DocTotalFC, odrf.DocTotal, odrf.DocRate, odrf.Comments, odrf.VatSumSy, odrf.DocTotalSy,odrf.NumAtCard,  odrf.CreateDate, odrf.DocNum, drf1.U_LCCP,
                          odrf.TaxDate, drf1.ItemCode, drf1.Dscription, drf1.Price, drf1.DiscPrcnt AS Expr1, drf1.Rate, drf1.Quantity, drf1.StockSum, drf1.unitMsr, drf1.BaseDocNum,drf1.LineTotal, nnm1.seriesname


    FROM         odrf INNER JOIN
                          drf1 ON odrf.DocEntry = drf1.DocEntry
    inner join nnm1 on odrf.series = nnm1.series 
    where ODRF.DocEntry = {?DocKey@} and odrf.ObjType = 15
```

---

UNION

---

2nd query
Here also I need to put an if statement which will check if the parameter (same parameter used in the 1st query) is equal to a specific  value.  If so, then this query will be executed.

```
SELECT     odln.DocEntry, odln.CntctCode,dln1.SubCatNum, odln.Address2, dln1.LineNum, odln.DocType, odln.CANCELED, odln.Handwrtten, odln.DocStatus, odln.Transfered, odln.DocDate, odln.DocDueDate,
                      odln.CardCode, odln.Printed, odln.CardName, odln.Address, odln.NumAtCard, odln.VatPercent, odln.VatSum, odln.VatSumFC, odln.DiscPrcnt, odln.DiscSumFC,
                      odln.DiscSum, odln.PaidToDate, odln.DocTotalFC, odln.DocTotal, odln.DocRate, odln.Comments, odln.VatSumSy, odln.DocTotalSy,ODLN.NumAtCard,  odln.CreateDate, ODLN.DocNum, dln1.U_LCCP,
                      odln.TaxDate, dln1.ItemCode, dln1.Dscription, dln1.Price, dln1.DiscPrcnt AS Expr1, dln1.Rate, dln1.Quantity, dln1.StockSum, dln1.unitMsr, dln1.BaseDocNum,dln1.LineTotal, nnm1.seriesname


FROM         odln INNER JOIN
                      dln1 ON odln.DocEntry = dln1.DocEntry
inner join nnm1 on odln.series = nnm1.series

where odln.DocEntry = {?DocKey@}
```

Comment: What is the issue?   You don't need an IF, just add your parameter to the two WHERE clauses.

Comment: well i need the if to specify wich query should run , as otherwise both of them will exicute and data will came from both quieris

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code:

```
SELECT Query1
WHERE Query1Condition = true
UNION ALL 
SELECT Query2
WHERE Query2Condition = true
```

No IF required, you will only get data from the query you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an IF statement: your UNION can handle this just fine.  See below:

```
SELECT     
    odrf.DocEntry, odrf.CntctCode,drf1.SubCatNum, odrf.Address2, drf1.LineNum, odrf.DocType, odrf.CANCELED, odrf.Handwrtten, odrf.DocStatus, odrf.Transfered, odrf.DocDate, odrf.DocDueDate,
    odrf.CardCode, odrf.Printed, odrf.CardName, odrf.Address, odrf.NumAtCard, odrf.VatPercent, odrf.VatSum, odrf.VatSumFC, odrf.DiscPrcnt, odrf.DiscSumFC,
    odrf.DiscSum, odrf.PaidToDate, odrf.DocTotalFC, odrf.DocTotal, odrf.DocRate, odrf.Comments, odrf.VatSumSy, odrf.DocTotalSy,odrf.NumAtCard,  odrf.CreateDate, odrf.DocNum, drf1.U_LCCP,
    odrf.TaxDate, drf1.ItemCode, drf1.Dscription, drf1.Price, drf1.DiscPrcnt AS Expr1, drf1.Rate, drf1.Quantity, drf1.StockSum, drf1.unitMsr, drf1.BaseDocNum,drf1.LineTotal, nnm1.seriesname
FROM         
    odrf 
     INNER JOIN
    drf1 ON 
        odrf.DocEntry = drf1.DocEntry
     INNER JOIN 
    nnm1 ON 
        odrf.series = nnm1.series 
WHERE 
    ODRF.DocEntry = {?DocKey@} and 
    odrf.ObjType = 15 AND 
    {?YourParam@} = YourFirstValue -- replace this with your data

UNION ALL

SELECT    
    odln.DocEntry, odln.CntctCode,dln1.SubCatNum, odln.Address2, dln1.LineNum, odln.DocType, odln.CANCELED, odln.Handwrtten, odln.DocStatus, odln.Transfered, odln.DocDate, odln.DocDueDate,
    odln.CardCode, odln.Printed, odln.CardName, odln.Address, odln.NumAtCard, odln.VatPercent, odln.VatSum, odln.VatSumFC, odln.DiscPrcnt, odln.DiscSumFC,
    odln.DiscSum, odln.PaidToDate, odln.DocTotalFC, odln.DocTotal, odln.DocRate, odln.Comments, odln.VatSumSy, odln.DocTotalSy,ODLN.NumAtCard,  odln.CreateDate, ODLN.DocNum, dln1.U_LCCP,
    odln.TaxDate, dln1.ItemCode, dln1.Dscription, dln1.Price, dln1.DiscPrcnt AS Expr1, dln1.Rate, dln1.Quantity, dln1.StockSum, dln1.unitMsr, dln1.BaseDocNum,dln1.LineTotal, nnm1.seriesname
FROM       
    odln 
     INNER JOIN
    dln1 ON 
        odln.DocEntry = dln1.DocEntry
     INNER JOIN 
    nnm1 ON 
        odln.series = nnm1.series
WHERE 
    odln.DocEntry = {?DocKey@} AND
    {?YourParam@} = YourSecondValue -- replace this with your data
```

Comment: thanx so much for all of u guys , i'll try ur solutions , best regards

Comment: Happy to help, please let us know if the solution works.